# Vue class equivalent for setup(){const { t } = useI18n({ inheritLocale: true, useScope: 'local' })}

Tags: vue.js, class, vue-i18n

I want to implement `i18n` for translating purposes and I know how to do it in Vue 3 like **:**

```
const { t } = useI18n({
      inheritLocale: true,
      useScope: 'local'
    })
```

and then something like **:**

```
{{ t('p1') }}
```

having **locales** configured beforehand. Now I've tried this working with classes **:**

```
export default class App extends Vue {
  i18n = new useI18n({});
}
```

and after that something like this in the html **:**

```
{{ i18n.t("p1") }}
```

and nothing happened. Can someone help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the solution was closer than I thought

just to add $ like this:

```
{{ $i18n.t("p1") }}
```

and it works, have not to add the aforementioned values...